# Can't Find Specific Listbox for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am right now looking for a way for a user to open a listbox, choose an option, and the program continues to run, considering the desired option. My best option was to use a listbox I found in the Settings section of the phone.

I don't have a way of explaining this control completely, so I'll use an example. If you go into the Regions & Language section of the phone and then hit Region, you will notice a list pops open. The same listbox is opened when choosing a ringtone. This is exactly what I need for my application. The only problem is, I don't know what it is called. Help!

I included two images

[image: Region and Display (open up the same list)]

[image: EXACTLY what I need (upon clicking Region format)]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for ... do you want to know how to create a list of entries identical to the ListBox under language settings on the phone? Or are you asking how to create one ListBox and then instantiate it in 2 places?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to create a box in which you touch and a list of items, simliar to the ones above, are displayed, with the current one hilighted. Isn't there already a pre-defined control in the Toolbox I can drag over and edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That control is not called a `ListBox`, Windows Phone calls it the `ListPicker`. [Here's](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx?Redirected=true) an article explaining how to use it.

The control is included in the [Silverlight Toolkit](https://silverlight.codeplex.com/) for Windows Phone.

Note that the article is old and a few of the properties for the control have been renamed / made read-only in the latest release of the toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the ListPicker from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888). You'll need to handle changing any settings yourself. This can be done through binding to a property that gets changed or via code that you write.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Language" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    FullModeHeader="LANGUAGES" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"
                    SelectionChanged="ListPicker_SelectionChanged">
    <sys:String>English</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Spanish</sys:String>
    <sys:String>French</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

If you need to handle changes:

```
private void ListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // handle any changes that are needed
}
```